# Electrical resistance of expander graphs

Tags: graphs, random-walks, expanders

Let $G$ be a $d$-regular expander graph. What is the electrical resistance of $G$? Is it a constant independent of the number of nodes $n$ once $d$ is large enough? If not, can we give matching upper and lower bounds in terms of $n,d$?

Comment: How does electrical resistance end up in graph theory?

Comment: Electrical resistance is a property of the graph. Roughly speaking, it measures its connectivity. It is also connected to hitting and commute times, hence the random walks tag.

Comment: Have you tried generating some examples and plotting the resistance as a function of $n,d$ for several different types of expander graphs?  You might want to edit your question to include what you've tried so far.

Comment: Please define your terms.  What is the definition of _electrical resistance_ of an edge/node/subgraph/graph?  What is an _expander graph_?  And what does it mean for an an expander graph to be _d-regular_?

Comment: here is a cool new simons institute article on the basic theory around this subject, some of it very advanced/deep [Network Solutions by Klarreich](https://www.simonsfoundation.org/features/science-news/mathematics-and-physical-science/network-solutions/), its all about the graph [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time you ask a question you should try to google it first. I googled "electrical resistance expander graph" and the [very first result](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~ruzzo/papers/resist.pdf%E2%80%8E) was a paper stating that $d$-regular graphs have resistance $\Theta(1/d)$.

Comment: Thanks. I did google it and perused the abstract of that paper, but missed the reference to expanders.